# Indoor routing without GPS iOS

Tags: ios, swift, location

hey I need to navigate users in indoor places like malls and I don't want to use GPS. Is there anyway to do that with gyroscope or acceleration sensor? Or do you have any other idea? suppose that we know users first location

Comment: Hello Amir_P,

Have you got any solution?

Comment: No, Unfortunately project got abandoned and I've never got to implement it. @PiyushSanepara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that if you have a map of the mall (or any place you want to get directions for).

Here's some apple documentation on [motion events](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/motion_event_basics/motion_event_basics.html)

It's not very hard to get user's direction and velocity. From there it shouldn't be too hard to apply these variables to the map / user position

Comment: I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

You can use iBeacon technology. https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/

Comment: That requires the indoor locations to actually have the physical beacons. The OP is talking about being able to give directions indoors in general, not in a specific place they'll have the option of placing additional equipment in.

Comment: @Amir_P Is my impression of what you're asking incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no native support for this without the use of the satellite positioning system employed by the GPS. The only way to achieve indoor navigation without the GPS would be via the use of a third party product such as https://www.nearit.com/ or as Roman says, beacons.

Comment: we can't use accessories to do that